# React using methods within a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, components

I'm trying to create a reference service component in React, it will hold all a map with bunch of data. I have the data loaded already, but I can't access the data from outside this component.

```
const ReferenceService = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const referenceTables = useSelector(selectReferenceTables);
  const referenceServiceStatus = useSelector((state) => state.referenceService.status);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(referenceServiceStatus === 'idle'){
      dispatch(loadReferenceTables())
    }
  }, [referenceServiceStatus, dispatch]);

  const getReferenceTables = () => {
    return referenceTables;
  };

  const getReferenceTable = (tableName) => {
    return referenceTables[tableName];
  };

}
export default ReferenceService;
```

I tried doing:

```
import ReferenceService from '../referenceService/ReferenceService';

const getRef = () => {
  console.log(ReferenceService.getReferenceTables());
}
```

and getting
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): *referenceService_ReferenceService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6*_.default.getReferenceTables is not a function

How would I rewrite this component so that I can access the functions?

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceService is not exporting getReferenceTables, put it out and export or change the logic

Comment: i tried that, but then I can't access the referenceTables from useSelector(selectReferenceTables);

Comment: Why not just make ReferenceService return referenceTables?

Comment: since I want to add other methods to it, like getReferenceTable which just return 1 of the table, and getEntry which parse though and only return one entry within one table

Answer (score 0):

found the solution..

i just had to add

```
return {getReferenceTables, getReferenceTable, getEntry};
```

to the ReferenceService
then add

```
const {getReferenceTables, getReferenceTable, getEntry} = ReferenceService();
```

to where i want to use it.